# Can't seem to log in using Parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have just started using Parse.com and I'm making a very simple login screen which has two forms for inputting a username and password (fUser and fPass respectively) and a submit button which onclick calls the function logueo. This is how I defined the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function logueo() {
            Parse.initialize("key1", "key2");
            var username = fUser.value;
            var password = fPass.value;

            Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
                success: function(user) {
                    console.log("Exito")
                },
                error: function(user, error) {
                    console.log("Mal")
                }
            }
        )};
```

I have created the users directly on Parse.com and whether I input a correct user or not, I always get the 'Mal' result. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please can you log error.message in the error callback? i.e. console.log("Mal" + error.message)  This will give some information about why the error is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `fUser.value` and `fPass.value`, I assume you're trying to pull the values of a text box or form element. However, in your `logueo()` function, `fUser` and `fPass` are treated HTML Element Objects, so likely, you are not passing any data to Parse to validate a login. If you are declaring those variables in another segment of code, they are likely outside the scope of your login function. I would recommend adding an `id` attribute to your username and password fields and referring to their respective values via a `var fUser = document.getElementById("ID-OF-USER");` and `var fPass = document.getElementById("ID-OF-PASS");` call. That should work. Just replace "ID-OF-PASS" and "ID-OF-USER" to the respective ID names.